# Concurrency exceptions when I tried to modifies two tables in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am having a concurrency Exception when I tried to update MessageTemplate and  TemplateLookup table. MessageTemplate table update fine but the error occur when the code tried to update TemplateLookup table. Any help will be appreciated

Error

```
 "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions."
```

Controller

```
     public async Task<ActionResult> Edit (MessageTemplate messagetemplate,int Id, bool Enable, int id)
        {
           TemplateLookup template = new TemplateLookup();
            var appdata = DateTime.Now;
            try
            {

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var currentUser = await _db.vwUsers.FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.DomainUserName == User.Identity.Name);
                    if (currentUser != null)
                    messagetemplate.LastUpdatedByUser = currentUser.FullName;
                    messagetemplate.LastUpdatedByUserID = User.Identity.Name;
                    messagetemplate.LastUpdatedOn = appdata;
                    //messagetemplate.Id = Id;
                    _db.Entry(messagetemplate).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    //await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
                    if (Enable == false)
                    {
                        var templateidlist = _db.TemplateLookups.Where(v => v.TemplateId == Id).ToList();

                        messagetemplate.Enable = Enable;
                        foreach (var templateid in templateidlist)
                        {
                            template.TemplateActive = Enable;
                            template.LastUpdatedOn = appdata;
                            template.LastUpdatedByUser = currentUser.FullName;
                            template.TemplateId = Id;
                           // Error occur here
                            _db.Entry(template).State = EntityState.Modified;
                        }                        
                    }
                    _db.Entry(messagetemplate).State = EntityState.Modified; 
                    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                return View(messagetemplate);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well as it says - it looks like the row is being modified in between your query being started and actually saved...

I noticed you change the Id:

```
template.TemplateId = Id;
```

which you also search on;

```
var templateidlist = _db.TemplateLookups.Where(v => v.TemplateId == Id).ToList();
```

So if this action is run twice with the same template Ids it may change them before the second one has a chance to run.

Ususally in this concurrent modification scenario you'd catch the exception and re-display the form with the new values - but it depends on your usecase we can't say without more information about what your application does...

You can read about various options to handle it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/concurrency